# SCHEME from list to its values

Tags: scheme

How can I convert this list

```
(define l list '(1 2 3 4) )
```

to its own value 1, 2, 3 and 4

I need to do this because I have a function

```
(define (push!  stk . args)
(stk 'push! args ) )
```

for this other function

```
((eq? msg 'push!) (set! stack (append (reverse args) stack)))
```

but the result I get when using push! is a list in a list, I don't want this

Answer (score 0):

You can by iteration. eg. `fold`:

```
(fold cons '() '(1 2 3 4))
; ==> (4 3 2 1)
```

Now the most stackie functional structure is the lisp list since it is a singly linked list that constructs from end to beginning while iterates from beginning to end.

Answer (score 0):

Go the other way instead - gather all the arguments in one list, and then `apply`:

```
(apply push! (cons the-stack l))
```